# sentence structure: S + 'was that' + independent clause

Tags: syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences

Is the structure '*was that*' + independent clause correct?

Example sentence:

> The major difference about these two groups **was that** they were composed entirely of young children

Comment: Simplify before you parse: (The difference about these groups) was (that they were composed of children) -> (The difference) was (that they were children) -> (The difference) is/was(are/were ...) (that (they were children)) -> (The difference) is/was(are/were ...) (that (IC))

Comment: That part of the sentence is perfectly fine. “The major difference about these groups”, however, sounds a bit odd. I would say, “What set these two groups apart” or something like that instead. If you use ‘difference’, the reader will be expecting to find what the differences are _between_.

Comment: You don't want to use *difference*; that is only used when you want to say that the two groups are not the same. You want to say: "The major *distinction of* these two groups was …"

Comment: ***Was that*** is not a constituent. All you're talking about is swapping the two [bracketed noun phrases] in the following sentence: *[**That** they were composed entirely of young children] **was** [the major difference about these two groups].*

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be misunderstanding the makeup of the sentence. It is not made up of

```
[subject] [was that] [independent clause]
```

Rather, it is:

```
[subject] [copula] [dependent clause]
```

In other words, *was that* is not a constituent that belongs together. The verb ‘to be’ is a [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29) (also known as a ‘linking verb’) that basically functions like an equals sign: it links a subject and its predicate (also known as ‘subject complement’ or a ‘predicative complement’), stating that one equals the other. So the following two are basically the same:

```
[subject] [copula] [predicate]
[subject] = [predicate]
```

Both the `subject` and the `predicate` above must be of a nominal type. That is, they must either be a noun phrase (such as “the major distinguishing feature of these two groups”) or a dependent noun clause (i.e., a dependent clause that can function as a noun). One type of dependent noun clause is the subordinate clause introduced by the conjunction ‘that’.

In your example, then, the `subject` is *the major distinguishing feature of these two groups*, a simple noun phrase; the `copula` is *was*, and the `predicate` is the dependent noun clause *that they were composed entirely of young children*.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is fine as is, but you've misunderstood the constructions that are involved.

Your sentence is in the form of a copular clause. What you have here is "Subject - Verb - Predicative Complement", and the predicative complement (PC) is a *content clause*, and the word "that" is a content clause subordinator. This is a way you can parse your sentence:

- [**Subject:** The major difference about these two groups] **Verb:** was [**PC:** that they were composed entirely of young children].

This subordinator "that" has no semantic meaning; rather, it is a marker that identifies the beginning of a content clause. (Note: This "that" is not a relative pronoun nor relative word.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all  .. The major difference BETWEEN these,   not ABOUT these.

1. "That"  in your sentence is the object of the verb "WAS"
2. "That" is also acting as a relative pronoun to join the two clauses.
    The major difference between the groups  (dependent )
    They were composed entirely of young children(independent)

Comment: :( Im sorry, but Im still confused. :(

Comment: The OP doesn't mean *between*. He wants to talk about the difference between these two groups on one hand, and typical groups on the other hand.

Comment: 1) As Peter says, this is _not_ a difference between these two groups—that would make the sentence nonsensical. 2) ‘That’ is _not_ the object of anything. 3) ‘Was’ is a copular verb and can therefore _not_ take objects. 4) ‘That’ is _not_ acting as a relative pronoun to join two clauses: it is a conjunction that introduces a subordinate clause, which functions as the subject predicate (or subject) in the sentence. 5) “The major difference between the groups” is _not_ a dependent clause, or a clause at all—it is a noun phrase. There is basically nothing in this answer that isn’t wrong. -1.

Comment: @Janus: I think the downvotes are completely unjustified here. The major ***problem with*** this question ***was that*** it gave a pointlessly confusing example usage. With no explanatory context, we've no way of knowing whether OP's intended meaning would be properly expressed using biloo's ***between***, or my ***with***, but there's no doubt in my mind that ***about*** could never be correct. I believe some grammars count *that* as a "relative pronoun", but the terminology itself seems almost irrelevant in respect of a question which simply asks *if the construction is "correct" English*.

Comment: @Fumble, ‘between’ just could not work in the example. “The major difference between them was that they were composed of children” makes no sense. What the real, intended meaning was is unclear; but simply substituting ‘between’ is not a valid option. And of course ‘that’ is a relative pronoun—when it sets off a relative clause. Not when it sets off a subordinate clause like this one, though. The fact that there are so many factual and terminological mistakes in this answer makes it a very confusing one. I can’t blame the asker for still being confused after reading this: it makes no sense.